# How to get a consistent export with Oracle Data Pump?

Tags: oracle, oraclexe, data-pump

I'm trying to obtain a consistent export (with data pump) from an schema emulating the `CONSISTENT=Y`. Currently I'm executing data pumb in this way:

```
'/ AS SYSDBA' schemas=arrels dumpfile=arrels.dmp nologfile=y flashback_time='2009-06-03 12:00:02'
```

But when importing shows errors about inconsistency:

```
ORA-02298: cannot enable name - parent keys not found
```

If the data pump export are working with `flashback_time` and, of course, the constraints are validated on export time:

- Why this is happening?
- Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to the problem. I put exactly the current timestamp:

```
flashback_time='2009-06-03 12:05:02'
```

If I put a sooner timestamp (for instance 5 minutes before) it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the schema you're exporting ('arrels') does not have referential constraints that refer to objects in other schemas? If one or more of the foreign key references in the arrels schema refer to tables in other schemas, then you'll have to export/import them as well.

EDIT: The documentation seems to indicate you need to specify the flashback time in double quotes, e.g.:

'... flashback_time='"2009-06-03 12:00:02"'

Another example I came across was to use the TO_TIMESTAMP function:

exp system/manager file=exp.dmp flashback_time=\"TO_TIMESTAMP('19-06-2004
13:24:26', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')\"

Also, you must have automatic undo management enabled to use this.

Comment: Sure, this is not the case.